# How can I put all the linerenderer test function under a gameobject parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject dotPrefab;
    public string numbers;

    private Vector3[] Positions;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        DrawNumber(0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("0"))
        {
            DrawNumber(0);
            numbers = "0";
        }
    }

    void DrawNumber(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0)
        {
            Zero();
        }
    }

    private void Zero()
    {
        Positions = new Vector3[7] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(1, -1, 0),
        new Vector3(1,-2,0),
        new Vector3(0,-2,0),
        new Vector3(0,-1,0),
        new Vector3(0,0,0)};

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 7;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(Positions);

        for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i++)
        {
            var dot = Instantiate(dotPrefab);
            dot.transform.position = Positions[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Each time I press on the key 0 it's creating another Zero but the first problem is that the new zero is on the same positions of the first zero so I want to put all the Zeros under a parent so each time I press on 0 it will create a new Zero gameobject child and also the new child will be in a bit different position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thats what you'r looking for.

```
private const float LETTER_WIDTH = 2f;

public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public GameObject dotPrefab;
public string numbers;
public Transform WordAnchor;//parent object to set all the letters under

private int currentLetterIndex = 0;
private Vector3[] Positions;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    DrawNumber(0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("0"))
    {
        DrawNumber(0);
        numbers = "0";
    }
}

void DrawNumber(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        Zero();
    }
}

private void Zero()
{
    Positions = new Vector3[7] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
    new Vector3(1, -1, 0),
    new Vector3(1,-2,0),
    new Vector3(0,-2,0),
    new Vector3(0,-1,0),
    new Vector3(0,0,0)};
    //Create a gameobject to parent the dots under
    GameObject letter = new GameObject(currentLetterIndex.ToString() );
    letter.transform.parent = WordAnchor;//parent the letter under the word
    letter.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(currentLetterIndex * LETTER_WIDTH, 0f, 0f);//move an offset base on the index


    LineRenderer lineRendererInstance = letter.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRendererInstance.positionCount = 7;
    lineRendererInstance.SetPositions(Positions);
    lineRendererInstance.useWorldSpace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i++)
    {
        var dot = Instantiate(dotPrefab, letter.transform);//parent the dot under the letter.
        dot.transform.localPosition = Positions[i];//set the relative position.
    }
    ++currentLetterIndex;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem. When I press on 0 for example three times it will create new 0 objects under the parent but all the new 0 objects are empty. I want to like duplicate the linerenderer so if I will move one of the new 0's positions I will see two zeros in the game.

Comment: I mean when I drag one of the 0's it's not moving the linerenderer lines. I want to be able to change the position of each drawn zero as an object.

Comment: Oh if you want to be able to move the line render in game you either need to shift all the positions by x amount or you can set the line renderer to useWorldSpace = false.